# number of real triplets $(x,y,z)$ in system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Total number of real triplets of $(x,y,z)$ in $x^3+y^3+z^3=x+y+z$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=xyz$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $x+y+z=a$ and $xy+yz+zx=b\;,$

Then $(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)=xyz\implies a^2-2b=xyz$

And using $\displaystyle x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)\left[x^2+y^2+z^2-(xy+yz+zx)\right]$

So we get $a-3xyz=a[xyz-b]\implies a+ab=(a+3)xyz$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{a+ab}{a+3} = a^2-2b$

Now how can I solve it after that, Help required, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the theory of symmetric polynomials (for example [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities)) could be useful.

Comment: I don't think the number is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x+y+z=a$ and $xyz=b$. We have:
$$ e_2 = xy+xz+yz = \frac{a^2-b}{2} $$
and we may consider that:
$$ p(t) = (t-x)(t-y)(t-z) = t^3 - e_1 t^2 + e_2 t^2 - e_3 = t^3 - at^2 + \frac{a^2-b}{2}t - b. $$
On the other hand, for any $w\in\{x,y,z\}$ we have $p(w)=0$ or
$$ w^3 = e_1 w^2 - e_2 w + e_3,\tag{1} $$
hence by summing $(1)$ over $w\in\{x,y,z\}$ we get:
$$ b=x^3+y^3+z^3 = a b - \frac{a^2-b}{2}a+3b \tag{2}$$
from which $b=\frac{a^3}{4+3a}$. The problem boils down to understanding which values of $a$ grant that
$$ p(t) = t^3 - at^2 + \frac{(a+2)a^2}{4+3a}\,t-\frac{a^3}{4+3a}\tag{3} $$
has three real roots, i.e. a non-negative discriminant. That cannot happen if $a>-3$, but happens for sure if $a$ belongs to some sub-interval of $\mathbb{R}^-$, so we have an infinite number of triplets fulfilling the given constraints.

Comment: Thanks Jack D'Aurizio, What will happen If $x,y,z>0$